# How to get index of item on swipe

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i need to get the index on swipe

file.html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item  on-swipe-left="warn('Must use scope',$index)">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" style="border-bottom:2px #ccc solid ;"> {{item.name}}</div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

file.js

```
    angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
      .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
         {name: 'item1'},
         {name: 'item2'},
         {name: 'item3'},
         {name: 'item4'},
         {name: 'item5'}];
    $scope.warn = function (message,$index) {
      alert(message,$index);
    };
 });
```

This shows only my alert message not my index
could some one help me

Comment: what index? could you be more precise?

Comment: @Subash Selvaraj consider that i have a list of 5 items that are swipe able i need to get its index on swiping any one of that item

Comment: Will you be using ng-repeat to render you items?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ng-repeat` to render your items, then you can get index by using `$index` of `ng-repeat` directive.
Below is the example,

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="swipe" on-swipe-left="warn('Must use scope', $index)">Swipe div</div>
  </body>

    angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
      .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
         {name: 'item1'},
         {name: 'item2'},
         {name: 'item3'},
         {name: 'item4'},
         {name: 'item5'}];

        $scope.warn = function (message, index) {
          alert(message, index);
        };
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item    on-swipe-left="warn('Must use scope',$index)">
        <div on-swipe="onSwiipe($index)" ng-repeat="item in items" style="border-bottom:2px #ccc solid ;"> {{item.name}}</div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>



$scope.items = [
         {name: 'item1'},
         {name: 'item2'},
         {name: 'item3'},
         {name: 'item4'},
         {name: 'item5'}];
    $scope.onSwiipe = function (ind) {
       console.log('on swipe ', ind);
    };
```